# Publishing Geoprocessing Service with ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I'm modeling [this ESRI tutorial](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Tutorial_Publishing_a_geoprocessing_service/00930000000r000000/) for creating geoprocessing service with ArcGIS Server and I'm getting this error when trying to publish the service:

> Service was published but cannot be started due to: Server object
>   instance creation failed on all SOC machines.  Server Object instance
>   creation failed on machine MyServer.  Cannot load tool: BufferAndClip:
>   Geoprocessing service initialization failed.

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10 against ArcGIS Server 9.3.  My mxd that has the model in it has been saved out as version 9.3.  Also my geodatabase is a 9.3 version.  The model works fine within the mxd.  The mxd and geodatabases and lyr files are located all in the same folder on the server (e.g. \\MyServer\ArcGIS Resources\Test\Test.mxd).

I have published map services before to this server with no issues, why I'm I getting this error?

Comment: It sounds like the workspace/environment for your desktop is operating correctly. perhaps you haven't defined that for the server?  http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w00000034000000

Comment: @Brad Nesom, I set the geo scratch workspace to a separate geodatabase that is located in the same folder as everything else.  I also tried to clear out the current workspace path (defined in the tutorial link), but every time I re-open the dialog it is pointing to my C drive.  How do I keep the current workspace clear for the geoprocessing env?  I bet this is my issue.

Comment: @BradNesom, ESRI said my error is because I'm trying to create a geoprocessing service using ArcGIS 10 against ArcGIS Server 9.3.  ArcObjects and the scripting language behind the geoprocessing tools has changed too much. I need to upgrade the Server to 10.

Comment: wish I had thought of that for more than a millisecond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esri said my error is because I'm trying to create a geoprocessing service using ArcGIS 10 against ArcGIS Server 9.3.

ArcObjects and the scripting language behind the geoprocessing tools have changed too much.

I need to upgrade the Server to 10.

Answer (score 4):

[Server object instance creation failed on all SOC machines](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/34171) is triggered when the SOC account does not have access to the resources that your trying to publish.

Try right clicking ArcCatalog and running it as the SOC account.  Can you browse to \MyServer\ArcGIS Resources\Test\ and able to see the MXD, layers and toolbox?

**Everything used in the model needs to be accessible to the SOC.**

See p[reparing resources for publishing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//00930000005v000000) for more details on how to setup the relevant permissions.

Comment: ESRI said my error is because I'm trying to create a geoprocessing service using ArcGIS 10 against ArcGIS Server 9.3.  ArcObjects and the scripting language behind the geoprocessing tools has changed too much. I need to upgrade the Server to 10.

Comment: ahhh... Maybe put that summary into a new answer and mark your own answer as the Answer.